# Running hokuyo node on Gumstix with Ubuntu

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm now following below two tutorials to install ROS on Gumstix.

#1 http://www.ros.org/wiki/Ubuntu%20Natty,%20ROS%20Diamondback,%20and%20Gumstix%20Overo
#2 http://www.ros.org/wiki/gumros/ubuntu

However, in tutorial #2, author said, "Create setup.sh as usual and source".
But, there is no clue about that. What should I do for this?

When I follow tutorial #1, install like below, it has "setup.sh" by default.

## rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=ros-base&overlay=no"

Do you think anything difference between tutorial #1 and #2?

And Second, I would like to use Hokuyo LRF node on Gumstix.
There are 6 dependencies to use hokuyo node.

diagnostic_updater
driver_base
dynamic_reconfigure
roscpp
self_test
sensor_msgs

However, I have no idea to install this.

And also, byte alignment error occurred.

Can you help me to this end?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12754/running-hokuyo-node-on-gumstix-with-ubuntu/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can live with an older distribution, there are .deb packages available for ROS Electric on Ubuntu Maverick and for ROS Diamondback on Ubuntu Lucid. These packages include pre-built laser drivers.

If you still want to install from source, try the following:

The first tutorial looks like the better one to follow; setup.sh and setup.bash are created by rosinstall.

Regarding dependencies: some of those may already be installed by default. If `rospack find <package>` returns true, then that package is already installed.

If a package isn't installed, you can use the dependency links to find stack containing that package, and get the source code with `rosco --distro=diamondback <stack>`

You can then start tracking that package with rosinstall by doing `rosinstall ~/ros <stack>`

Don't forget to install the dependencies for your dependencies. This may be a bit of chase.

If you have to install pcl_ros, I suggest you edit the CMakelists.txt and Makefile and remove any parallel-build options ( `-j` or `-j<N>` )

Once you have all of your dependencies downloaded, you should build your laser drivers using rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1